# Linux Mint out-of-box install: How to Replace Cinnamon with icewm

Tags: linux-mint, icewm

I am currently using Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon. Nothing unusual, just the main download available when one goes to the Mint website. (I can update to the latest 18.2, if that is needed.)

This is what I want to do:

1. install `icewm`
2. make it the default/only windows manager
3. remove ALL of what I do not need anymore

Any answers for EITHER removing package no longer used after I switch to `icewm` OR removing any default Mint/Ubuntu packages a developer doesn't need would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "all of what you do not need any more"? Only other window managers? Or any other optional software?

Comment: Well, I'm mostly concerned with mem usage while running. But to answer your question more directly, I want to clean up by uninstalling packages that were being used by the default Cinnamon setup, but are no longer being used after switching to icewm.

Comment: But you have me a great idea. If you know a good way to quickly remove unused optional software from the default Mint install (all I do is code and use a web browser), that would be swell.

Comment: Best to update your question with the clarifications so that current and future answerers have good information to go on.

Comment: "_remove ALL of what I do not need anymore_" how are we supposed to know what you do or don't need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `icewm`, set it as `x-session-manager` (via `update-alternative`), maybe install `slim` as very slim and simple graphical login manager (to also get rid of the former one, but `mdm` or `LightDm` are surely not too blown up).
You might also want to install `spacefm/pcmanfm/rox`, which each will provide a possibility for having a desktop (`xfdesktop4` should also work fine), and search the net for a copy of `IcePref` for a settings GUI.

Then do `apt-get remove  --purge *cinnamon*` to get rid of all old cinnamon stuff. An `apropos "window manager"` can help you find more old stuff which you maybe installed

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Sounds like I got all I need. I'll try it and get back to you.